# how to join pipe delimited data file with a table data in python or linux

Tags: python, linux, db2

Is there any possibility to join pipe delimited data file with a db2/oracle table data in python or linux and get the match and fetch the matched records from table into a final file.

```
without copying file data into a temp table , is there any possibility ?
```

Pls let me know if my question is not clear or repeated question..

Answer (score 1):

Use [EXTERNAL TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r_create_ext_table.html), if you are on Db2 11.5 for Linux, Unix and Windows.

If you use earlier versions, and your file / pipe is accessible from database server, you can write your own JAVA / C table function reading such a file. Such a function may be implemented even as [Generic table function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/c0057283.html) in JAVA.

Comment: Thanks a lot mark for the reply. Is this external table remains only for a particular session ?

Comment: Can we copy data from Main table to External table ?

Comment: There are 2 types of external tables: named and transient. Both types are described at the 1-st link I provided. Briefly: A definition of named table is stored in the Db2 system catalog, you work with it as with regular table (with some restrictions, of course). A transient table doesn't have any system catalog definition and can be used in a single query referenced by its path on disk. All examples at this link at the bottom use transient external tables. Search by the `external table` expression in the Knowledge Center for more examples.